# Java: how to convert a class datatype array to a String array?

Tags: java, arrays, types

New to programming, I'm trying to convert an array of a class datatype to an array of the datatype String.

I.E:

```
Class[] array;

String[] stringArray;
```

Is this possible? Should I use a parse method?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  it all depends on what you want to do with that string afterwards.  To answer your question, you can look at serialization, converting to XML, or converting to JSON.  However, *WHY* are you trying to convert a class to a string?  What do you hope to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to convert an array of a class datatype to an array of the datatype String

Well, the only way to do it, which makes sense is like this

```java
Class[] classes = {Runnable.class, RuntimeException.class};
String[] strings = new String[classes.length];

var curPos=0;
for(var c : classes) {
    strings[curPos]=classes[curPos].toString();
    curPos++;
}

for(var str : strings) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Does this solve your problem?
Tell me in the comments.
Also, why exactly do you want a transformation like this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although it entirely depends on what you are expecting the resulting strings to look like. Do you want the class name? The fully qualified name? Something else? You can do something similar to this, depending on what you need:

```
Class[] array = ...;
String[] stringArray = Arrays.stream(array).map(Class::getName).toArray(String[]::new);
```